# OnActivityResult not triggered on finish

Tags: android, android-activity, mirah

The following application works as expected:

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import android.app.WallpaperManager

class ChwallActivity < Activity
  def onCreate(state)
    super
    setContentView R.layout.main
  end

  $Override
  def onStart
    super
    Intent intent = Intent.new(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
    intent.setType "image/*"
    startActivityForResult Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 0
  end

  $Override
  def onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data:Intent)
    super
    thumb = BitmapFactory.decodeFile "/storage/sdcard0/download/foo.jpg"
    manager = WallpaperManager.getInstance self
    manager.setBitmap thumb
  end
end
```

This executes a gallery-picker in an infinite loop, which is undesirable.  However, if I insert a `finish` at the end of the `onStart()` function, `onActivityResult()` doesn't seem to be called: the wallpaper doesn't change to foo.jpg.  Is `onActivityResult()` being called when the gallery starts up the second time?  What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the `finish` in `onActivityResult()` works.

Answer (score 2):

Move the following code to `onCreate` and it should work well

```
Intent intent = Intent.new(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
intent.setType "image/*"
startActivityForResult Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 0
```

Comment: ... and where do I put the `finish`?

Comment: at the end of `onActivityResult` I think

Answer (score 0):

`OnStart()` is called again when Activity becomes visible again, after picker Activity finishes, which starts picker Activity again, and so on.

You shouldn't put that logic in `onStart()` instead have a user event launch the picker.

OR

You could use a `boolean` flag to track if you've picked the picture already.